# GL_MAX_EXT for glBlendEquation

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

Is this equation unavailable for opengles? [docs of glBlendEquotation](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendEquation.xml) says it is but

[Is it possible to achieve MAX(As,Ad) openGL blending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143690/is-it-possible-to-achieve-maxas-ad-opengl-blending)

says otherwise. Is this only for iphone? I am working with libgdx/opengl es.

I want to blend some cloudy textures together but I don't want to add alpha of textures, final alpha should be maximum alpha that is written on that pixel. How can I achieve such a thing on opengl es?

Well, looks like `Gdx.gl20.glBlendEquationSeparate(Gdx.gl20.GL_FUNC_ADD, 0x8008);` works for my PC emulator and my phone `(0x8008 is GL_MAX_EXT)` but I guess that is not guaranteed.